# Rotate and move UIImageView at the same time

Tags: objective-c, animation, uiimageview, uiimage, image-rotation

Read other questions on this subject but they didn't help much. I'm trying to move the `UIImageView` with this... I want it to orbit around a point:

```
- (void)orbit {
    orbitAngle -= orbitSpeed;
    float x = stillObject.frame.origin.x + orbitRadius * cos(orbitAngle * M_PI / 180);
    float y = stillObject.frame.origin.y - orbitRadius * sin(orbitAngle * M_PI / 180);
    CGRect oldFrame = orbitingObject.frame;
    CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(x, y, oldFrame.size.width, oldFrame.size.height);
    [orbitingObject setFrame:newFrame];
}
```

I'm rotating the `UIImageView` with:

```
- (void)rotate {
    orbitingObject.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(rotateDegree * M_PI / 180);
}
```

I'm doing the rotation and orbiting "animations" like this rather than actual animations because I have more control since I can just call the function when I want it to advance to the next "frame".

Anyway, both of these methods work perfectly fine by themselves. But when I use them together, things go crazy! If someone could help me figure out how to get the two methods to work together, that'd be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do translate and rotation together using successive CGAffineTransformations.

```
- (void)transformImageView {
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;

    float translateX =  orbitRadius * cos(orbitAngle * M_PI / 180);
    float translateY =  orbitRadius * sin(orbitAngle * M_PI / 180);

    CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, translateX, translateY);

    CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, rotateDegree * M_PI / 180);

    orbitObject.transform = transform;
}
```